# qtconcurrent no matching function for call to 'run'

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

To log the user in I have a method in the following class`class ProbeConnection : public QObject, QRunnable`.

The method to login is called run as is expected for the QRunnable class.

```
void ProbeConnection::run(QString username, QString password, QString ipAddress, bool fts, bool tts, bool pcap, bool events, bool os_meas)
```

The method needs to run in a different thread as it is blocking the gui when there is no response (the method is used for logging in).
I tried to get it to run with `QtConcurrent` by running:

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this->run(username, password, ipAddress, fts, tts,  pcap,  events,  os_meas));
```

But the message i get is:

> no matching function for call to 'run'

How can I start the run method when it takes parameters?

Comment: why don't you use this method https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#tryStart  ?

Answer (score 0):

When Calling `QtConncurrent::run` with a member function you need correct `QtConncurrent::run` syntax as answered in  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996253/qtconcurrent-with-member-function)

As highlighted in [Multi-threading Technologies in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html) ; `QRunnable` would be used when you want to reuse existing threads in a *QThreadPool* , On the other hand `QtConcurrent`  would usually be used for its high level API, and returns a QFuture object to retrieve results from threads.

To use `QRunnable::run` , reimplemet it in subclass and use `QThreadPool::start()` to put the `QRunnable` in the QThreadPool's run queue  ... NOT by calling `QtConcurrent::run`

In your code, both `ProbeConnection::run` and `QFuture<void>` are `void` .. and I see no reason for using `QtConcurrent` .. or use it directly without a `QRunnable`.

Comment: > "I see no reason for using QtConcurrent".
To easily run a function in another thread seems like a good reason to me.

Comment: @GrecKo, `QRunnable::run` by itself is designed to run in `QThreadpool` as described, not within a `QtConcurrent` ; moreover, whats the point when the function is `void` ,  how would `QFuture<void> QtConcurrent::run`  be different?

Comment: Simpler to use. `QtConcurrent::run(foo, &Foo::function, parameter)` vs having to inherit from `QRunnable`, overriding the `run` function and starting that in a `QThreadPool`.

Comment: @GrecKo, that's right, it could be simpler,  yet other _statics_ are also simple. don't know why OP opted for `QRunnable::run` , the essence of my answer is how to implement each and not mix them.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#choosing-an-appropriate-approach